# Reading from a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(item.getInputStream()));
    String strLine = "";
    StringTokenizer st = null;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, "\t");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            urlcnt = st.nextToken();
            srccnt = st.nextToken();
            contentType = st.nextToken();
            verticle = st.nextToken();
            timeFrame = st.nextToken();
        }
        if (con == null) {
            SQLConnection.setURL("jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.2.53\\SQL2005;user=sa;password=365media;DatabaseName=LN_ADWEEK");
            con = SQLConnection.getNewConnection();
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        }
        try {
            ResultSet rs;
            boolean hasRows = false;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select url from urls_temp where url='"+urlcnt+"'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                hasRows=true;
                i++;
            }
            if (!hasRows) {
                j++;
                PreparedStatement insertUrlStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO urls_temp(url, source_name, is_active, is_periodic, Link_Type, New_Entry, verticle, periodic_timeframe) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                if (timeFrame.equalsIgnoreCase("Daily")) {
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(1, urlcnt);
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(2, srccnt);
                    insertUrlStatement.setInt(3, 1);
                    insertUrlStatement.setInt(4, 0);
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(5, contentType);
                    insertUrlStatement.setInt(6, 1);
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(7, verticle);
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(8, timeFrame);
                    insertUrlStatement.executeUpdate();
                    insertUrlStatement.close();
                } else {
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(1, urlcnt);
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(2, srccnt);
                    insertUrlStatement.setInt(3, 1);
                    insertUrlStatement.setInt(4, 1);
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(5, contentType);
                    insertUrlStatement.setInt(6, 1);
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(7, verticle);
                    insertUrlStatement.setString(8, timeFrame);
                    insertUrlStatement.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is used for uploading details to the database that are given tab separated in a CSV file.

Sample format of CSV file will be as follows and this works fine:

`http://avb.com(tab space)asdf(tab space)asdf(tab space)asdd(tab space)asdf`

`http://anything.com(tab space)asdf(tab space)asdf(tab space)asdfasd(tab space)asdfsadf`

Sometimes I may need some `null` values to be inserted into the database from the CSV file as follows:

`http://asdf.com(tab space)(tab space)aasddf(tab space)(tab space)asdfsad`

But this is not working, nothing is getting inserted into the database.

What modification has to be done to the above program for inserting `null` values in the second and fourth (`srccnt` & `verticle`) columns of the table?

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  Where are the `catch()` and/or `finally` clauses for the `try` statements?  If you're ignoring exceptions, then that's the place to start... print the stack traces.

Comment: "But this is not working.. Nothing is getting inserted in to the DB." ... tells me that you are getting some form of error. Secondly, you are tokenzing on \t but you have a space after \t in case of "http://asdf.com(tab space)(tab space)aasddf(tab space)(tab space)asdfsad" ... this will return a "space" token right? If you dont want spaces then you should get rid of them before tokenizing. Something like strLine.replaceAll("\\w+","") should do the trick. Also use split() instead of tokenizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StringTokenizer treats consecutive delimiters as a single delimiter. You say the input contains [tab space] as delimiters, but the rest of your code doesn't seem to be expecting spaces so, without more information, I'm going to guess that the input is delimited only with tabs (not [tab space]), and the adjacent delimiters are being ignored, Then the last `nextToken()` throws an exception which you are ignoring.

The answer here is to rewrite this using `split()`, as recommended in the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that
>   is retained for compatibility reasons
>   although its use is discouraged in new
>   code. It is recommended that anyone
>   seeking this functionality use the
>   split  method of String or the
>   java.util.regex package instead.

That said, you should look at any of the existing CSV libraries out there (Google for Java CSV).

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to debug your code to figure out more specifically where it's not behaving as you expect and then, if necessary, post a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I use FileHelpers for parsing csv files. http://www.filehelpers.com/. It reads a csv file and gives me an output in object, which is what I desire. And also if I pass the list of objects it would create a csv file for me. Give it a chance.